# Full dump of Android to use to flash another deivce?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, flashtool

I'm looking to dump the full rom (system, boot, bootloader) of a device.  But I don't want to dump it in parts, I want the whole thing in one image.  Is this possible?  I have full root on the device.

I'll then take that image and burn it into another device using software provided by the chip manufacture.

Comment: Just to check: are these two devices both the same model/hardware? The image won't work otherwise. It would be much easier to get a flashable image from the manufacturer.

Comment: @DanHulme Yes, they are exactly the same.  Tried to get the flashable image from manufacture but they aren't responding.  Also googled around a lot...

Comment: @Alexis What are the devices???

Comment: ***[\[GUIDE\] Making Dump Files Out of Android Device Partitions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450045)***

Answer (score 1):

Moving one device's rig to another? No problem! All you need is:

1. one large SD card/USB-OTG
2. TWRP (You have root, so this will be easy) on **both devices**

**Part one- getting TWRP** If you have TWRP already, skip this.

1. Download TWRP manager from [this google play link.](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.jmz.soft.twrpmanager%26hl%3Den_GB%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dtwrp%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_kdSwV_rrLMzTgAbg1qyQBw&ved=0ahUKEwi6-LK838HOAhXMKcAKHWArC3IQ8oQBCBwwAA&usg=AFQjCNH6kAHnAd04x5h01klmqXfWL4rT-g&sig2=xWDqXyJo1XiB2qfcCw4izA)
2. Install TWRP from the install section. **Make sure you select the right make and model**
3. Follow on-screen prompts. Check recovery when done.

**Part two- Doing the dirty work**
Now what we are here for :)

1. Boot into TWRP. You don't need to, but mount EVERYTHING (**except** efs)
2. Begin the Backup operation from the appropriately named tab. Tick all, **except** External SD, USB OTG and EFS. (Note- Ext. SD and USB-OTG are normally not options) ensure it is saving to an external SD or USB, however. Also, enable compression to get one, neat file.
3. Twiddle your thumbs and contemplate the meaning of life, the universe, and everything while the backup happens.
4. When done, power down (from TWRP'S reboot menu) and Pop your external storage into the other device.

5.Use TWRP'S Restore (Yep, restore) function to install the zip. You will be asked what segments you want to use, so pick what you need, and flash!

6.Well, slow dimmer lightbulb. Might take a while. Go read a book.

7. Reboot normally, and you should be done!

***Why no EFS?***
EFS tends to contain **UNIQUE ID's**, like you MAC address and IMEI. Two devices should **not** share the same EFS partition.

Comment: Shouldn't the option at point 5 be **Restore**, rather than **Install**? Just asking.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Ah, yes. Sorry, I've just fixed it :)